# AWS APP MESH ENVOY sidecar [error] Could not retrieve credentials listing from the instance metadata

Tags: amazon-web-services, envoyproxy, aws-app-mesh

I'm using AWS App Mesh with ECS Fargate. Unfortunately in the logs of the envoy sidecar I see errors like:

> ```
> [error][aws] [source/extensions/common/aws/credentials_provider_impl.cc:94] Could not retrieve credentials listing from the instance metadata
> ```

> ```
> [1][warning][config] [bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/source/common/config/_virtual_includes/grpc_stream_lib/common/config/grpc_stream.h:93] StreamAggregatedResources gRPC config stream closed: 16, Missing Authentication Token
> ```

Permission: AWSAppMeshFullAccess

I already checked the [AWS App Mesh Userguide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/app-mesh/latest/userguide/app-mesh-ug.pdf)

```
{

 "name" : "envoy",
 "image" : "840364872350.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/aws-appmeshenvoy:v1.15.1.0-prod",
 "essential" : true,
 "environment" : [
 {
 "name" : "APPMESH_VIRTUAL_NODE_NAME",
 "value" : "mesh/apps/virtualNode/serviceB"
 },
 {
 "name": "ENABLE_ENVOY_XRAY_TRACING",
 "value": "1"
 }
 ],
 "healthCheck" : {
 "command" : [
 "CMD-SHELL",
 "curl -s http://localhost:9901/server_info | grep state | grep -q LIVE"
 ],
 "interval" : 5,
 "retries" : 3,
 "startPeriod" : 10,
 "timeout" : 2
 },
 "memory" : "500",
 "user" : "1337",
 "portMappings": [
      {
        "containerPort": 9901,
        "protocol": "tcp"
      },
      {
        "containerPort": 15000,
        "protocol": "tcp"
      },
      {
        "containerPort": 15001,
        "protocol": "tcp"
      }
    ],
 "ulimits": [
      {
        "softLimit": 15000,
        "hardLimit": 15000,
        "name": "nofile"
      }
    ],
 "requiresCompatibilities" : [ "FARGATE" ],
 "taskRoleArn" : "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:role/ecsTaskRole",
 "executionRoleArn" : "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
 "networkMode" : "awsvpc"
 }
```

Comment: Even I am facing similar problem #eks #eksfargate

Answer (score 0):

Have you configure Proxy Configuration for you ECS Task to ignore metadata IP?

It similar this

```
            proxy_configuration=ecs.AppMeshProxyConfiguration(
            container_name='envoy',
            properties=ecs.AppMeshProxyConfigurationProps(
                app_ports=[80],
                proxy_egress_port=15001,
                proxy_ingress_port=15000,
                ignored_uid=1337,
                egress_ignored_i_ps=[
                    '169.254.170.2', '169.254.169.254'
                ]
            )
        )
```